# PHP sessions are lost between different pages

Tags: php, session

I have 2 different pages on the same website and same domain, one is responsible for the login on the website and set of the sessions, the second page is responsible for other tasks using the session established on the first page.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

//login checks and set of variables, for commodity lets use fixed values
$id = 10;
$name = "test";

//set of the sessions
$_SESSION['member_id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['member_name'] = $name;
session_write_close();
header("location: ../different_page.php");
?>
```

different_page.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

//dumping session for test purpose and check whats inside
var_dump($_SESSION);

if(!isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {
    exit('ID not set');
}

echo $_SESSION['member_name'];
?>
```

The result of the different_page.php

```
array(0) { } ID not set
```

What could it be the issue? I have no idea at this point.

Comment: `session_write_close();` ends the session, that is probably what is clearing your values. Try to leave that out.

Comment: @Ood Are you sure about that? `session_write_close` I thought just closed the session from being written to.. e.g. it releases the lock so other requests can run for the same user

Comment: @user3783243 from the PHP documentation: `session_write_close — Write session data and end session`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: @Ood It ends the session in the current script, it doesn't destroy it, so it should be usable by the next script.

Comment: @Ood I tried removing the lock, but the same still happens, session is not present in the second page

Comment: There's no need to use `session_write_close()` at the end of a script, since it happens automatically when the script exits.

Comment: Is the `<?php` line really indented as you show? If you have any whitespace before that, you'll get a "Headers already sent" warning and the session cookie won't be set.

Comment: @Barmar no the <?php does not have any whitespace, it appear like this on stackoverflow because of the formatting

Comment: Either use 4-space indentation or triple backticks to indicate a code block, not both, then it won't be confusing.

Comment: I copied the exact code from your question onto my server, and my result is: `array(2) { ["member_id"]=> int(10) ["member_name"]=> string(4) "test" } test`. Did you test the code in your question in the same way? Or did you extract it from a larger code base, and never actually tested it yourself?

Comment: Check your PHP error log for that warning.

Comment: @Barmar do you happen to have an anydesk or something? maybe it's some sort of mistake on my end, I can show you the full code

Comment: @KIKOSoftware could it be a misconfiguration of the web server then? I am using CWP, what could it be?

Comment: PHP sessions are independent of the webserver.

Comment: [Enable full error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/283366) and see if anything pops up

Comment: Do you see the `PHPSESSID` cookie in the browser?

Comment: My best guess is that your real login page never actually sets the tested session variables.

Comment: @Barmar oh, you're right. the pages both have different PHPSESSID, they are not the same. What could be the reason?

Comment: That might happen if you call `session_destroy()` in the first script.

Comment: Debugging steps... 1) Open a new incognito / private browsing window in your browser. 2) Open dev-tools and select the _Network_ panel. 3) Open the `login.php` page, select the top request in the dev-tools and check the `Set-Cookie` response header. 4) Open `different_page.php`. Check the `Cookie` request header. The value should be the same one you received from `Set-Cookie` previously. There should be no `Set-Cookie` response header for `different_page.php`

Comment: @Phil I tried your suggestion, but, there is no Set-Cookie found in both pages

Comment: Did you enable full error reporting [as mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609359/php-sessions-are-lost-between-different-pages?noredirect=1#comment136821340_77609359)? Definitely sounds like a _"headers already sent"_ issue

Comment: I found the issue. it was a mere problem related the domain... first page was https with www and the second page was https without www so the cookie was one for www and one without www.

Comment: _"first page was https with www and the second page was https without www"_ - not sure how you managed that - when the "move" from the first to the second page is done via `location: ../different_page.php`, then how could host name and protocol change?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that even though the two pages are on the same domain, you have a structure of this kind:

```
folder1
    different_page.php
    folder2
        login.php
```

Due to the different folders, your app creates a session for each of your folders. You have two main types of solutions.

First. You could have a same `index.php` file at the same location that would respond to any requests and you would set up rewrite rules on your server to translate whatever request is supported into a request to `index.php`, allowing you to have a single session without worries. This is the approach I favor. In your example, your `different_page.php` would be translated into an `folder2/index.php?req=different_page` which would, on its turn include/require `different_page.php`.

Second. You could use [session-set-cookie-params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set the path of your request. Something like

```
$nrOfHours = 4;
session_set_cookie_params(60*60*$nrOfHours, "/folder2");
```

I have never used this second approach, because it does not seem very intuitive to always check which path your request points to. It makes the code messy. So, I personally favor setting this inside the server with rewrite rules. A good those of the right regular expressions and a well-defined convention will remove this trouble for good.

Answer (score -2):

First, I think using **session_start()**   in all the pages aren't actually the best practice. You should consider starting session from the database connection file then use **require "[database connection file]" ** at all pages requiring the session.
You can try this suggestion

Comment: What database connection file? Also, you **must** add `session_start()` to any page requiring use of the session

Comment: "I think using session_start() in all the pages aren't actually the best practice."- why do you think that?